# Cassandra HeartBeat logs

Tags: cassandra, logback

I am using cassandra in my spring application. Everytime a request comes or connection is idle, cassandra is printing heartbeat DEBUG logs through logback of my application. I want to stop these heartbeat logs in my debug logs.

```
2016-11-03 11:37:27,241 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-2] [com.datastax.driver.core.Connection] [line : 1093 ] [] - Connection[/10.41.123.31:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
2016-11-03 11:37:30,990 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-6] [com.datastax.driver.core.Connection] [line : 1023 ] [] - Connection[/10.41.123.31:9042-6, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2016-11-03 11:37:30,991 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-1] [com.datastax.driver.core.Connection] [line : 1023 ] [] - Connection[/10.41.123.31:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2016-11-03 11:37:30,990 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-5] [com.datastax.driver.core.Connection] [line : 1023 ] [] - Connection[/10.41.123.31:9042-5, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2016-11-03 11:37:30,990 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-7] [com.datastax.driver.core.Connection] [line : 1023 ] [] - Connection[/10.41.123.31:9042-7, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2016-11-03 11:37:30,993 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-5] [com.datastax.driver.core.Connection] [line : 1093 ] [] - Connection[/10.41.123.31:9042-5, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
2016-1
```

Comment: You need to configure the logger used by the driver in your logback.xml and set the log level to some level above DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

What logger are you using?

If you are using log4j you can configure the debug level like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public Application()  {
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("log4j.rootLogger", "INFO, A1");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
}
```

Then the heartbeats should not longer be printed out.